# Join on several tables and return data which could or could not exist in one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The following posts relates to querying a SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50) database. Please ignore the poorly named views and tables as they don't follow best practices in naming conventions.

I have a view and three tables that I need to join and display various pieces of information from to create a .NET front-end interface. The goal is to capture the following columns:

- `AccountID`
- `Account` (name)
- `oYear` (year)
- `Scenario`
- `ProductID`
- `f_m1` - `f_m12` (forecasted units for each month)
- `a_m1` - `a_m12` (actual units for each month)

for a given product ID, year, and scenario. This will be the final return table, but will contain actual sales data.

[image]

Allow me to elaborate on the views and tables:

- `vw_account_tree` contains all accounts in the database. Most importantly, I'll be referencing the `AccountID` and `Account` fields in the final result, and joining on the `AccountID` field. The `atree.level3 IN()` limiter inside the `WHERE` clause simply limits the accounts returned.
- `tbl_forecast_packworks` contains forecast data entered manually by the user and contains `AccountID`, `ProductID`, `Units`, `Scenario`, `oMonth`, and `oYear` fields.  This is where units data for `f_m1` - `f_m12` will be pulled from. Most importantly, I need the query to return data (a 0 in each forecast column) for a given account even if an entry does not exist for a given account, product, scenario, month, and year.
- `tbl_salesdata` contains actualized sales data. This is where units data for `a_m1` - `a_m12` will be pulled from.  Most importantly, I need to join on the `CustomerID` field and reference the `UnitsGrossSales` (units), but it also contains `oYear`, `oMonth`, and `ProductID`.
- Lastly, `tbl_customers` simply contains a link between `CustomerID` and `AccountID` - which is the only reason it's included in the query.

I've constructed the following query, but it is not accurately returning the actual units `a_m1` - `a_m12`:

```
SELECT atree.AccountID
,atree.Account
,ISNULL(forecast.oYear, 2014) oYear
,ISNULL(forecast.Scenario, 'CF') Scenario
,ISNULL(forecast.ProductID, '01227P') ProductID
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 1 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m1
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 2 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m2
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 3 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m3
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 4 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m4
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 5 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m5
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 6 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m6
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 7 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m7
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 8 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m8
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 9 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m9
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 10 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m10
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 11 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m11
,SUM(CASE WHEN forecast.omonth = 12 THEN forecast.Units ELSE 0 END) f_m12

,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 1 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m1
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 2 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m2
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 3 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m3
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 4 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m4
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 5 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m5
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 6 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m6
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 7 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m7
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 8 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m8
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 9 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m9
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 10 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m10
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 11 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m11
,SUM(CASE WHEN sales.omonth = 12 THEN sales.UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m12
FROM vw_account_tree atree
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Packworks_Forecast forecast on forecast.AccountID = atree.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Customers cust on cust.AccountID = forecast.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_salesdata sales ON sales.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID
WHERE (
    forecast.oYear = 2014
    OR forecast.oYear IS NULL
    )
AND (
    forecast.ProductID = '01227P'
    OR forecast.ProductID IS NULL
    )
AND (
    forecast.Scenario = 'CF'
    OR forecast.Scenario IS NULL
    )
AND atree.level3 IN ('ABC', 'BKR', 'CAT', 'CCO', 'DRM', 'DKS', 'DRT', 
'PJC', 'KAT', 'LCL', 'MCK', 'MET', 'PRO', 'SFY', 'SDM', 'SBN', 'TAR', 
'TMK', 'UPX', 'WMK', 'ZEL')
GROUP BY atree.AccountID
,atree.Account
,forecast.oYear
,forecast.Scenario
,forecast.ProductID
ORDER BY atree.Account
```

It's important to note that the both the `ISNULL` value and the values in the `WHERE` clause for `oYear`, `Scenario`, and `ProductID` are values fed programmatically so that it will match the user's search conditions.  I am using these columns as hidden fields in the code for when the user makes changes and attempts to save the forecast.

Does anyone have any advice?  Right now, the actual units columns are returning data which does not exist, e.g. 3546 units for a month when actually there are 0 units for that month in the `tbl_salesdata` table.  I think I need to either tweak the `WHERE` clause, or change up how I'm crafting the query completely.  Please let me know if you need any more information, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand your problem, i think i figure out what you wanted to do, i think this code will help you, but if it really worked for you don't forget to rate my answer hhhh :

```
SELECT
         atree.AccountID
        ,atree.Account

        ,temp_tab.oYear
        ,temp_tab.Scenario
        ,temp_tab.ProductID
        ,temp_tab.f_m1
        ,temp_tab.f_m2
        ,temp_tab.f_m3
        ,temp_tab.f_m4
        ,temp_tab.f_m5
        ,temp_tab.f_m6
        ,temp_tab.f_m7
        ,temp_tab.f_m8
        ,temp_tab.f_m9
        ,temp_tab.f_m10
        ,temp_tab.f_m11
        ,temp_tab.f_m12

        ,temp_tab.a_m1
        ,temp_tab.a_m2
        ,temp_tab.a_m3
        ,temp_tab.a_m4
        ,temp_tab.a_m5
        ,temp_tab.a_m6
        ,temp_tab.a_m7
        ,temp_tab.a_m8
        ,temp_tab.a_m9
        ,temp_tab.a_m10
        ,temp_tab.a_m11
        ,temp_tab.a_m12

FROM
    vw_account_tree atree
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT     
         COALESCE(forecast.AccountID, forecast.AccountID)   AS AccountID 
        ,COALESCE(forecast.oYear, forecast.oYear)           AS oYear
        ,COALESCE(forecast.Scenario, forecast.Scenario)     AS Scenario
        ,COALESCE(forecast.ProductID, forecast.ProductID)   AS ProductID
        ,forecast.f_m1
        ,forecast.f_m2
        ,forecast.f_m3
        ,forecast.f_m4
        ,forecast.f_m5
        ,forecast.f_m6
        ,forecast.f_m7
        ,forecast.f_m8
        ,forecast.f_m9
        ,forecast.f_m10
        ,forecast.f_m11
        ,forecast.f_m12
        ,sales.a_m1
        ,sales.a_m2
        ,sales.a_m3
        ,sales.a_m4
        ,sales.a_m5
        ,sales.a_m6
        ,sales.a_m7
        ,sales.a_m8
        ,sales.a_m9
        ,sales.a_m10
        ,sales.a_m11
        ,sales.a_m12
        FROM 
            (SELECT
                     AccountID
                    ,ISNULL(oYear,2014) oYear
                    ,ISNULL(Scenario,'CF') Scenario
                    ,ISNULL(ProductID,'01227P') ProductID
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 1 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m1
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 2 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m2
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 3 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m3
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 4 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m4
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 5 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m5
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 6 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m6
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 7 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m7
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 8 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m8
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 9 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m9
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 10 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m10
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 11 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m11
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 12 THEN Units ELSE 0 END) f_m12
            FROM
                tbl_Packworks_Forecast
            GROUP BY
                     AccountID
                    ,ISNULL(oYear,2014)
                    ,ISNULL(Scenario,'CF')
                    ,ISNULL(ProductID,'01227P') ) forecast
        FULL OUTER JOIN 
            (SELECT
                     cust.AccountID
                    ,ISNULL(oYear,2014) oYear
                    ,'CF' Scenario
                    ,ISNULL(ProductID,'01227P') ProductID
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 1 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m1
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 2 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m2
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 3 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m3
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 4 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m4
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 5 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m5
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 6 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m6
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 7 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m7
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 8 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m8
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 9 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m9
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 10 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m10
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 11 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m11
                    ,SUM(CASE WHEN omonth = 12 THEN UnitsGrossSales ELSE 0 END) a_m12
            FROM
                tbl_salesdata sales
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                tbl_Customers cust
                    ON  sales.CustomerID = cust.CustomerID
            GROUP BY
                     cust.AccountID
                    ,ISNULL(oYear,2014)
                    ,ISNULL(ProductID,'01227P') ) sales
                ON  sales.AccountID = forecast.AccountID
                AND sales.oYear     = forecast.oYear
                AND sales.Scenario  = forecast.Scenario
                AND sales.ProductID = forecast.ProductID) AS temp_tab
        ON  temp_tab.AccountID = atree.AccountID            

WHERE
        atree.level3 IN ('ABC', 'BKR', 'CAT', 'CCO', 'DRM', 'DKS', 'DRT', 
                        'PJC', 'KAT', 'LCL', 'MCK', 'MET', 'PRO', 'SFY', 'SDM', 'SBN', 'TAR', 
                        'TMK', 'UPX', 'WMK', 'ZEL')

-- Filter
AND     ISNULL(oYear,2014) = 2014
AND     ISNULL(ProductID,'01227P') = '01227P'
AND     ISNULL(Scenario,'CF') = 'CF'

GROUP BY
         atree.AccountID
        ,atree.Account
        ,temp_tab.oYear
        ,temp_tab.Scenario
        ,temp_tab.ProductID
ORDER BY
        atree.Account
```

I hope this will help you...
Good Luck!!

Comment: Is it what you was looking for?

Comment: Hi Youssef. I'm not quite sure.  Unfortunately, the Scenario column does not exist in the tbl_salesdata table. Once I removed that field from the subquery and the GROUP BY statement, SQL Server threw the following compilation error: `Column 'temp_tab.f_m1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`